# ProcessBuilder gives a "No such file or directory" while Runtime().exec() works fine

Tags: java, playframework, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I have an application, running on the Playframework, which needs to encode some video files. I used

```
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execCode)
```

for this (and it works perfectly), but as I need both, the output stream and the error stream, I am trying to use ProcessBuilder (as is also recommended).

But I cannot get it to work (testing on a MacBook). Is there a fundamental difference between the Runtime method and the ProcessBuilder?

This is my code for ProcessBuilder (exactly the same code works when replaced by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`)

```
    String execCode = "/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i file [...]"; 
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(execCode);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.directory(new File("/Users/[...]/data/"));
    Process pr = pb.start();
```

This is the console output:

```
11:00:18,277 ERROR ~ There was a problem with with processing MediaFile[13] with error Error during coding process: Cannot run program "/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/[...]/data/media/1/1/test.mov [...] /Users/[...]/data/media/1/13/encoded.mp3" (in directory "/Users/[...]/data"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.lang.Exception: Error during coding process: Cannot run program "/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/idoms-server/data/media/1/1/test.mov -y -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -b:a 64000 -vn -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 5 -trellis 1 -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate -1 -bufsize -1 -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30  -g 30 -async 2 /Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/idoms-server/data/media/1/13/encoded.mp3" (in directory "/Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/idoms-server/data"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at logic.server.MediaCoder.encodeMediaFile(MediaCoder.java:313)
    at logic.server.MediaCoder.doJob(MediaCoder.java:54)
    at play.jobs.Job.doJobWithResult(Job.java:50)
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:146)
    at play.jobs.Job$1.call(Job.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/idoms-server/data/media/1/1/test.mov -y -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -b:a 64000 -vn -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 5 -trellis 1 -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate -1 -bufsize -1 -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30  -g 30 -async 2 /Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/idoms-server/data/media/1/13/encoded.mp3" (in directory "/Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/idoms-server/data"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at logic.server.MediaCoder.encodeMediaFile(MediaCoder.java:189)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You need to specify the arguments as separate `Strings`:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "arg1", "arg2", ...);
```

The constructor accepts `String`, `varargs`, and `List<String>`.

See [ProcessBuilder documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: also I cant find `FSTL` on that list

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Saved me from stress.

Comment: Same problem with ffmpeg as well, this saved my day; if command is the command you would use with exec(), a simple command.split(" ") should do the trick

Comment: If the constructor accepts a string, why do we need to specify the arguments as separate Strings (varargs) ?

Comment: @RiccardoCossu command.split(" ") does not always work where the command has a string argument that has spaces. Something like `sh talk.sh "Hello World"` will break the String "Hello World" into pieces.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to break your commands into tokens everytime, you could try

```java
new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", execCode); // Linux / Unix terminal
```

OR

```java
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", execCode); // Windows command line
```